# How to plot fast-fourier transform data as a function of frequencies in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, fft, shapes

I am new to Scipy and still learning about structuring data in the NumPy array. Can someone please help me resolve the following :

My data array consists of 10 columns and 110 rows. I am unable to get the right number of freq points.

I want to:

1. Match the array shapes to ultimately plot frequency points using scipy's `rfftfreq`
2. Pad zeros to my data before computing th fast fourier transform

Here is my code:

I am converting the dataframe to numpy array and extracting `x` and `y` data

```
xdata=np.array(combine.iloc[:,0:20:2])          #both x and y data shapes are (110,10) #the data corresponds to positions in mm 
ydata=np.array(combine.iloc[:,1:20:2])
```

I compute the fft:

```
fftdata=fft(ydata)                             # array of 110 by 10 
fftlen = len(fftdata)                          # size is 1 and value 110
time = (2*fftlen*xdata*0.0075e-3)/c/1e-12      # the numbers are constants #time axis is generated from x data with different delay position of the laser beam
timestep=abs(xdata[fftlen-1]-xdata[0])/(fftlen-1)/0.1499 #sampling rate

sample_size=fftdata.size                        # size is 1 and value of 1100

freq = rfftfreq(sample_size, d=timestep)        
# shape is (551,) - (N/2)nyquist points 

plt.plot(freq,fftdata[0:(fftlen//2+1)])
```

But, I am getting this error

```
Error : x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (551,) and (56, 10)
```

I understand that these cannot be plotted due to different shapes. But I would like to apply FFT to the whole of my array (110,10) instead of loading individual files to different NumPy arrays. I would very much appreciate it if anyone could also help me with padding zeros to `xdata` and `ydata` before computing the FFT to improve the frequency domain resolution.

Comment: There is some elements missing in your questions. To what corresponds x and y. I suspect that x is time and that y is some given signal. is that right? Do you know your sampling rate ? Are the time-steps (x axis  ticks I suppose ) regular ? what does time and timesteps correspond to in your code ?

Comment: @inarighas: X and Y are my raw data. X is the data corresponding to positions (in mm) and Y is the signal. I get my time axis from positions (x data) and timestep is my sampling rate. Scipy's rfftfreq takes the sample spacing as a second argument which is the inverse of the sampling rate (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfftfreq.html). I have added some comments based on your useful feedback.

Comment: You need to have fixed known value for7 you sampling rate or a column for time values. Since you compute the `fft` without specifying `d` parameter (default to 1) and you compute time steps based on the result. Thats source of big problems.   If you want padding you just add zeros using basic numpy operations.

Comment: @inarighas I am specifying the 'd' parameter as timestep which is my sampling rate. The sample rate comes from the measured delay positions. Specifying sampling rate is not the issue here. For a 1D array, I can get my FFT result and frequency points with the same sampling rate (i.e. d = timestep). The problem is when the array is 2D, how do I get the frequency axis because the array shapes don't match? Hope this clarifies my problem further.

Comment: If you want to perform fast fourier transform on 2D data you need to use `fft2` (see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft2.html) If your 2D array contains just data of two independent (1D) signals, i suggest to one fft for each signal instead of gathering everything in one operation.

Answer (score 1):

The example in numpy documentation is all you need :

```
import numpy as np

# Let's say here is your signal
signal = np.array([-2, 8, 6, 4, 1, 0, 3, 5, -3, 4], dtype=float)

fourier = np.fft.rfft(signal)
n = signal.size
sample_rate = 100
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=1./sample_rate)
```

```
>> freq
 array([  0.,  10.,  20., ..., -30., -20., -10.])
```

but when you apply `rfftfreq`, you get only positive frequencies:

```
freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(n, d=1./sample_rate)
```

So if you want to plot something you take only the corresponding half of values (in the fourier transform magnitude for example).

```
>> freq
 array([  0.,  10.,  20., 40., 50.])
```

To perform zero-padding, you can just use `np.pad`

```
np.pad(signal, (2,2), 'constant', constant_values=(0,0))
```

This added 2 zero values in the beginning and the end of the array. Multiple options are possible. Check this https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html